# How do you do FlashPunk-style animation in libGDX?

Tags: 2d, animation, libgdx

In FlashPunk, you can have multiple animations set, and then choose which one to play at any time, and it'll do it.

Example:
    animatedSprite.add("running", [0, 1, 2, 3], 50);
    animatedSprite.add("falling", [4, 4, 4, 5, 1], 50);
    animatedSprite.play("running");

How do you accomplish this in libGDX?

I can only make it play one animation, looping, and I have no idea how to add multiple.

Comment: You can actually store the animation data in a texturepack. You have to name the images as they are sequenced. http://blog.isys-labs.com/swf-animation-in-libgdx-with-texturepacker/

Comment: Yes, but how do you choose between different animations? I can only get to constantly play, say, "walking". How do I make it so I can choose between "jumping" and "walking" and "running", etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it out of the box with libGDX.

I don't know how you structure your game but personally i would simply load all the animations for a particular sprites has `Animation` instance and store them in a map where i associate a name to each one of them.

So basically:

```
Map<String, Animation> animations = new Map<>();
animations.put("walk", /*...*/);
animations.put("run", /*...*/);
```

And then just write a simple method that takes the name of animation, fetch the corresponding in the animations map and set this animation as the current animation.

```
public void play(String name) {
    this._currentAnimation = animations.get(name);
}
```

Then in your rendering method, you just need to refer to the `_currentAnimation` field of your `Sprite` class or whatever and play this animation as explained [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation).

EDIT: libGDX provides create tools for game development but sometimes you'll need to write some higher level code that wraps libGDX concepts to do what you want. libGDX is not a game engine, it's a framework, this way, it provides a lot of flexibility on how you want to implement things.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of that! Great idea.